# Can BizTalk publish a single one and two way web service?

Tags: wcf, biztalk, wcf-binding, biztalk-2010

I am publishing a WCF service, using schemas not orchestrations, and using the BizTalk 2010 wizard. Some of my methods are one way and others are request/response. I finished the wizard successfully, published the services (hosted in IIS) and things were going fine until I went to import the bindings to my app.

There is only one Port, and one receive location connected to it, and its URI is something like /BizService.FTW/BizService.svc. The receive Port is marked as two way, so I can't bind my orchestrations that are one way to it. You cant have two receive locations pointed to the same URI, so my question is this; did the Wizard pull a fast one on me or is there a way to publish one and two way methods in a single service? If there is no way(using the wizard to do it) can I at least have two services (say at /BizService.FTW/BizService.svc and /BizService.FTW/BizServiceRR.svc ) coming from the same Web App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but BizService and BizServiceRR would be two separate 'services'.

However, for the one-way Orchestration, did you consider Direct Binding and setting up a Filter for that particular message type?

Comment: It sounds like your asking if I had thought of direct binding all my one way orchs and then publishing WCF services for those schemas? This would mean I don't need to import bindings for them upon publication but other than that I don't see an advantage.

Comment: No, you would publish the two-way service (someone has to respond) and that can be Specify Later.  But for all the One Way Orchestrations, they can simply subscribe to the Request message on a one way (Orchestration) Receive Port.

Comment: I was probably not clear above; my goal is to publish all of these orchestrations as web services(one and two way). Having the one way orchs all subscribe to the message box doesn't seem to achieve this(unless I'm misunderstanding you again).

Comment: Ok, I think I see now.  No, you cannot have one-way and two-way operations mixed in the same service.  I think that's more of a SOAP thing.  So, you need one Service (endpoint, URL, Receive Port/Location) with all you two-way operations and one Service with all the one-ways.  Maybe the Wizard doesn't check for that, I've never actually tried to publish a mixed Service.

Answer (score 1):

I'll recommend you publishing two biztalk services (one-way and two-way ones). And build a WCF service, that will route requests to Bzt. services, based on request schema.